# TypeError: constructor returned NULL

Tags: python, windows, gtk, gtk3, msys2

```
from gi.repository import GLib , GObject
from multiprocessing import Pipe
parent,child = Pipe(duplex=False)
```

some code....

```
parent,child = Pipe(duplex=False)
```

some code...

```
GObject.io_add_watch(parent.fileno() , GObject.IO_IN , myfonction )
```

***Then I get this error:***

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.5\threading.py", line 914, in `_bootstrap_inner`
self.run()
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.5\threading.py", line 862, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "mnG.py", line 1091, in
test = Thread(target=(lambda : GObject.io_add_watch(parant.fileno(),  GObject.IO_IN, self.up)),name="GObject")
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.5\site-packages\gi\overrides\GLib.py", line 749, in io_add_watch
channel, priority, condition, func, user_data = _io_add_watch_get_args(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\msys64\mingw64\lib\python3.5\site-packages\gi\overrides\GLib.py",  line 729, in _io_add_watch_get_args
real_channel = GLib.IOChannel.unix_new(channel)
TypeError: constructor returned NULL
```

***But this small code is working correctly on Linux (debian).
Why? How to have a valid file descriptor from parent?***

Comment: IIRC, `multiprocessing.Pipe` uses an `os.pipe` for half-duplex, not a `socketpair`. On POSIX systems this just calls `pipe()`, which is obviously fine. On native Windows, that Python emulates `os.pipe` on top of `CreatePipe` and `_open_osfhandle`, which should also work. But on MinGW Windows, you're using whatever MinGW does to emulate `pipe()`, which presumably isn't sufficient.

Comment: It's possible that you could work around this by using a full-duplex pipe even though you don't need one (which should work with `socketpair`, so it should give you whatever MinGW does to emulate Unix sockets (which I think is something like a loopback TCP socket plus a kernel Event for signaling?), which might work. If not, you'll probably have to drop to a lower level. For example, you could write a class that wraps a loopback UDP socket and pickle things over it the same way `Pipe` does (or just use the socket directly).

Comment: If the _only_ thing you want to do with this pipe is pass it to Glib, and you don't care about any of the multiprocessing stuff on top of it, the simplest solution is probably to try `os.pipe`, `os.mkfifo`, `socket.socketpair`, a (MinGW-emulated) Unix-domain socket, and a UDP localhost socket; one of them is bound to work, and it'll be a lot simpler and easier to understand what's going on than the opaque multiprocessing type.